# How to design a mutable collection of Mutex?

Tags: multithreading, collections, rust, mutex, borrow-checker

I need to have a mutable collection of `Mutex` that needs to be shared between multiple threads. The purpose of this collection is to return for a given key a list of `MutexGuard` (to be able to synchronize the threads depending on the key). Please note that when initialized, the collection has no `Mutex` in it, these need to be created at runtime depending on the key.

My code is the following:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};

struct Bucket {
    locks: HashMap<String, Mutex<()>>,
}

impl Bucket {
    // This method will create and add one or multiple Mutex to the 
    // collection (therefore it needs to take self as mutable), according 
    // to the give key (if the Mutex already exist it will just return
    // its MutexGuard).
    fn get_guards(
        &mut self,
        key: impl Into<String>,
    ) -> Vec<MutexGuard<'_, ()>> {
        let lock = self.locks.entry(key.into()).or_default();
        vec![lock.lock().unwrap()]
    }
}

impl Default for Bucket {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            locks: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // I need to wrap the bucket in a Arc<Mutex> since it's going to be shared
    // between multiple threads
    let mut bucket = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Bucket::default()));

    // Here I need to get a list of guards, so that until they are dropped
    // I can synchronize multiple threads with the same key (or to be more
    // precise with the same MutexGuards, as different keys may yields the
    // same MutexGuards).
    let guards = {
        // IMPORTANT: I need to unlock the Mutex used for the `bucket` (with
        // write access) asap, otherwise it will nullify the purpose of the
        // bucket, since the write lock would be hold for the whole `guards`
        // scope.
        let mut b = bucket.lock().unwrap();
        b.get_guards("key")
    };
}
```

[Link to Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8f16b66eb66c4383ef73182651d85a4b)

The error I am getting is the following:

```
error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:29:9
   |
27 |     let _guards = {
   |         ------- borrow later stored here
28 |         let mut b = bucket.lock().unwrap();
29 |         b.get_guards("key")
   |         ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
30 |     };
   |     - `b` dropped here while still borrowed

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Is there a way to design my `Bucket` collections of `Mutex` so that I can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to borrow an object from a locked one and keep it after it's enclosing object is unlocked.

Non-Static borrows are not possible in this case because this is not safe, *e.g.*, *any other thread may drop the owner of the object that you previously borrowed*.

According to your logic, inner `locks` needs to be shared between other threads safely you need to wrap your `mutexes` with `Arc`.

```rust
struct Bucket {
    locks: HashMap<String, Arc<Mutex<()>>>,
}
```

And this will return the atomic reference of inner mutexes.

```rust
//previously get_guards
fn get_mutexes(&mut self, key: impl Into<String>) -> Vec<Arc<Mutex<()>>> {
    let lock = self.locks.entry(key.into()).or_default();
    vec![lock.clone()]
}
```

You can simply lock all the mutexes you need like this:

```rust
let mutexes = bucket.lock().unwrap().get_mutexes("key"); // locks(borrows bucket's guard) temporarily in here
let guards: Vec<MutexGuard<'_, ()>> =
    mutexes.iter().map(|guard| guard.lock().unwrap()).collect();
```

Please see full code on [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e1c87916425778326684f2a009a05bd)